# IDEA always shows "Unable to import maven project: see the log for details"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My IDEA always shows "Unable to import maven project: see the log for details", the online method has been tried a lot, no effect.

My network environment is the company's internal network and currently accesses the external network through a proxy. I am using local maven,The proxy is set in IDEA, and is also set in the local maven.This is my setting about the proxy.
[image]
[image]

This is my setting about maven：
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have now created a new blank project, and then paste the pom file into it. Every time reimport reports this error, the same pom file is no problem on someone else's machine.
[image]

Prompt me to open the error log：

[image]
I don't know how to deal with this problem. It has been modified for several days or it has no effect.

Comment: try delete the .ides directory and reimport your project

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by reinstalling Maven, which is very strange.